# Dynamic Routing in Next js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm working on an E-commerce website and  using dynamic routing in Next.js .route is redirect on category page but when I click any
category it shows 404 page due to route being like this

> localhost:3000/category/category/female

I don't understand why the route repeats "category" two times

Comment: How are you navigating to the new category page ?

Comment: Can you show us how your file directory is setup & some code examples of how you're pushing your route.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its necessary to precede the href with `/` when its not meant to continue the current href.

For example,
If you are on URL,
`http://localhost/category/`

and your anchor tag is like,
`<a href="category/female">Link</a>`

You might have the behaviour you mentioned,
You just need to put,

`<a href="/category/female">Link</a>`

This behaviour will be similar with `next/link` as well.